# SQL Query using distinct and max

Tags: sql, select, subquery, distinct, max

I have a dataset like:

```
 type    seqID    text     
 A       1        Text1a
 A       2        Text2a
 A       3        Text3a
 B       1        Text1b
 B       2        Text2b
```

How do I get the row back by type with the highest seqID grouped by type?  So in the above example I would want the row that has A, 3, Text3a and B, 2, Text2b returned.

Comment: which server you are using? mysql/oracle/sql server?

Comment: Shouldn't it be " So in the above example I would want the row that has A, 3, Text3a" and not " So in the above example I would want the row that has A, 3, Text3a and B, 2, Text2b returned." ??

Comment: no i want b, 2, Text2b returned as well

Comment: @chris , before downvoting, you might want to clarify the question. We are here to help each other!

Comment: @chris : I understood the question (you want max seqID row for each type). See if my solution works for you now.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *  
FROM tmp t1  
WHERE NOT EXISTS  
(SELECT 1 FROM tmp t2 WHERE t1.type = t2.type AND t2.seqID > t1.seqID)
```

It shouldn't exists any other row with the same type and higher seqID.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.* FROM
(
   SELECT type, MAX(seqID) as maxId 
   FROM Table
   GROUP BY type
) m
INNER JOIN Table t ON m.maxId = t.seqId
```

Using CTE

```
;WITH maxIds(maxId)
AS
(
   SELECT type, MAX(seqID) as maxId 
   FROM Table
   GROUP BY type
)
SELECT t.* FROM
Table t
INNER JOIN maxIds m ON m.maxId = t.seqID
```

Answer (score 0):

You kind of need an ID, but since "Text" seems unique for this example

```
CREATE TABLE #TMP 
 (type VARCHAR(3),   seqID  INT,   [text] varchar(256))
insert #TMP values ('A'   ,    1   ,     'Text1a')
insert #TMP values ('A'   ,    2   ,     'Text2a')
 insert #TMP values ('A'   ,    3   ,     'Text3a')
 insert #TMP values ('B'   ,    1   ,     'Text1b')
 insert #TMP values ('B'   ,    2   ,     'Text2b')


SELECT * FROM #TMP T
where [text] IN
    (SELECT TOP 1 [text] FROM #TMP t2 WHERE t.type = t2.type ORDER BY t2.seqID DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tbl.*
FROM
   ( SELECT type, MAX(seqID)
     FROM tbl
     GROUP BY type) maxes
WHERE
   tbl.type= maxes.type AND
   tbl.seqID= maxes.seqID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SQL Server 2005+, you could use a [ranking function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) (more specifically, [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)):

```
SELECT
  type,
  seqID,
  text
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY seqID DESC)
  FROM atable
) s
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #tlb1(
[type] VARCHAR(3), seqID  INT, [text] varchar(max)
)

declare @type varchar(3), @text varchar(max);
declare @seqID int;
declare seq_cursor cursor for 
select [type], max(seqID) from tbl group by [type]
open seq_cursor
fetch next from seq_cursor into @type,@seqID
while(@@fetch_status=0)
begin
    set @text= (select [text] from tbl where [type]=@type and seqID=@seqid);
    insert into #tlb1 values (@type, @seqID,@text);
    fetch next from seq_cursor into @type,@seqID    
end
select * from #tlb1
close seq_cursor
deallocate seq_cursor
truncate table #tlb1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT type, max(seqID),text 
FROM 'db'
GROUP BY type
```

As easy as that.

Answer (score -1):

EDITED solution. Consider this a psuedo-code (since I am not familiar with SQL server syntax):

```
SELECT a.type, a.seqID, a.text FROM table a
 JOIN
(SELECT type, max(seqID) seqID FROM table GROUP BY type) b 
ON a.seqID = b.seqID AND a.type=b.type
```

Comment: `LIMIT` is not Sql Server function

Comment: this won't work, it won't return the B, 2, Text2b data row only the one with seqID 3

Comment: @sll : My answer said 'if' `LIMIT` is supported, then you can use it. What do you mean by 'not Sql Server' function? Is the OP talking about a particular DB server type? I didn't see it in his/her question.